# Fastest way to bulk insert data from collection to the table in SQL database

Tags: canvas, patch, powerapps, collect

I am trying to find the fastest way to bulk insert my data from collection to the table in SQL database.

I have tried simple:

```
collect(rep.SQLTable, colCollection)
```

however for 200 records it takes more than 3 minutes and I find it unacceptable, I would like to achieve it in a few seconds.

I have also tried combination of ForAll and Patch with Defaults but it took even longer.

Can any users share their experience on what is the fastest way to do it?